# can Déjà Dup backup all the applications?

Tags: backup, restore

Déjà Dup backup usually backs up the home folder.

Is there any way that it could backup my whole system (including all the applications)? How can I do that? Suppose my system crashes and I had a backup, I need it to be the same as before after the restore from the backup is done. How can I do that?

Comment: did you read this post? http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools

Comment: I don't find the answer for my question there